# How to add a point at the circumference of the polar plot at a specific angle in python?

Tags: python, plot

I want to plot a point at the circumference of the polar plot at the given angle. Let's consider the plot given bellow, [image]

Now, I want to add a point at the circumference at the specific angle, let's say at 45-degree.

I have used 'plotly.graph_objects' to get the polar plot. The code is

```
graph_title = 'title'
bins2 = 360
count, bin = np.histogram(angles_list, bins=bins2)

fig7 = go.Figure()
fig7.add_trace(go.Barpolar(
    r=count,
    theta= bin,
    width=5,
    name='11-14 m/s',

    marker_line_color="black"
))
fig7.update_layout(
    title= graph_title,
    font_size=12,
    legend_font_size=5,
    title_x= 0.5
)
fig7.show()
```

Than you.

Comment: If you post your current code, we can extend it, but overall you simply need another `plt.plot(x, y, 'go')` where x and y are tha cartesian coordinates of that point, say `x = rho*np.cos(np.pi/4)`

Comment: Without `angles_list` I cannot reproduce it. Also, what is `go.`? I am not complaining, it is just to be able to help

Comment: Thank you. I have shifted to  'plt.' it is easy and it is working.